# How to Call Method in a activity just once?

Tags: java, android

I have an android application that in main activity(Home Page) I call a method and show a message. and when I go to other activity that message hides and again when come to Home page that will be shown. But I can not show this message again. I want to be show just for first time. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you showing the message in `onResume()` ??

Comment: EIther show the message in onCreate, or use a flag and only show the message when the flag is true (setting the flag to false once the message has been shown).

Comment: Use SharedPrefences. Please read on this

Comment: use sharedpreferences or static boolean field.

Comment: @Tom, just call the method 1ce in onCreate method. That should do it my friend.

Comment: I call it in onCreate method.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

static boolean msgShown = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!msgShown)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyMsg", 1000);
        msgShown = true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Now when I go to other fragment and come back to Home this show again.